# Using embedded MongoDB database for tests in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I have MongoDB database for production purposes and also I am trying to use embedded MongoDB database for testing purposes. I am following this tutorial: [Spring Boot Integration Testing with Embedded MongoDB](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-embedded-mongodb). I added this dependency to my `pom.xml` file:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
        <version>4.11.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

and I created this test:

```
@DataMongoTest
public class MongoDbSpringIntegrationTest {


    @DisplayName("given object to save"
            + " when save object using MongoDB template"
            + " then object is saved")
    @Test
    public void test(@Autowired MongoTemplate mongoTemplate) {
        // given
        DBObject objectToSave = BasicDBObjectBuilder.start()
                .add("key", "value")
                .get();

        // when
        mongoTemplate.save(objectToSave, "collection");

        // then
        assertThat(mongoTemplate.findAll(DBObject.class, "collection")).extracting("key")
                .containsOnly("value");
    }
}
```

However, when I run the test it always connect to my production database. I tried several things such as creating a custom MongoDB configuration and an `application-test.properties` file to configure database name and uri but none of these solved my problem. I think, I don't have to do these configurations at all because `@DataMongoTest` taking care of all these configurations. So just adding the `de.flapdoodle.embed` dependency and the test I used in the above (`MongoDbSpringIntegrationTest`) would be enough to connect embedded MongoDB database. However, non of these work and my test always connect to the production database. So my question is how can I connect my test to embedded MongoDB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would highly recommend you use something like [Testcontainers](https://java.testcontainers.org/modules/databases/mongodb/) if your environment is using Docker. We've used this very embedded database and ended up switching to Testcontainers because of general instability and lack of feature support(like transactions if I correctly recall).